# How to add two rows to google sheets using appendRow with scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to add two rows to google sheet posted from my external application. right now I am just running it twice.

```
destSheet.appendRow(['',                 //A
    dataParsed.parameter.date,           //B
    '***',                               //C
    dataParsed.parameter.pnr,            //D
    dataParsed.parameter.first_pax,      //E
    dataParsed.parameter.adults,         //F
    '0',                                 //G
    '**',                                //H
    '***',                               //I
    '**',                                //J
    'N/A',                               //K
    'N/A',                               //L
    dataParsed.parameter.lineM,          //M
    '',                                  //N
    '',                                  //O
    dataParsed.parameter.agent,          //P
    dataParsed.parameter.lineQ,          //Q             
    dataParsed.parameter.int_note,       //R
    dataParsed.parameter.exe_note,       //S
    '******)',                           //T
    dataParsed.parameter.tickets,        //U
    dataParsed.parameter.f__l_date,      //V
    '',                                  //W
    '',                                  //X
    '',                                  //Y
    dataParsed.parameter.****            //Z
    ]) ;

destSheet.appendRow(['',                 //A
    dataParsed.parameter.date,           //B
    'K**',                               //C
    dataParsed.parameter.pnr,            //D
    dataParsed.parameter.first_pax,      //E
    '***',                               //F
    '0',                                 //G
    'LY',                                //H
    '***',                               //I
    '***',                               //J
    'N/A',                               //K
    'N/A',                               //L                  
    dataParsed.parameter.TKT_total,      //M
    '',                                  //N
    '',                                  //O
    dataParsed.parameter.agent,          //P
    dataParsed.parameter.TKT_total,      //Q   
    '',                                  //R
    '',                                  //S
    '=iferror(sum(M:M-Q:Q))'             //T
    ]);
```

The problem is that the google sheet is very large and it is taking a long time for each row to be inputted (about 10 seconds for the first row and another 10 seconds for the second row). Anyone know a way to add two rows at the same time without the delay in between?

Comment: Sheets API to append the data. Or use `setValues`

Comment: Consider also reducing the formula complexity of your sheet

Comment: Thanks but I am using the Sheets API and I cannot use setValues. I cannot reduce the complexity of the sheet either.

Comment: The code above uses the Spreadsheet Service, not the Sheets API.